# Fill Web Form with Data from Excel and Log Resutls

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, webforms

I'm not too well trained on JavaScript and mainly code in VB. I am looking for a solution to what I thought was going to be a simple problem. I have a large, 150,000+ row worksheet of people to look up in an online database. I need to look each in a webform and log the number of times the combination is found. There are a few problems I can't overcome:

1. The version of IE we use is old and we cannot update it due to a critical program relying on the version's architecture
2. The webpage will not function in IE because of the outdated version
3. There's no way we could obtain direct access to the database to run a query

The process I envision is as follows:

```
Open Chrome
Nav to webpage
Fill Form with data
Submit Form
Obtain Result
Clear Form
Repeat 3-6 Until Last Row
```

I know I have critical pieces of the puzzle left out of my code, Like how to open Chrome, nav to the page, and wait til the page is loaded to check for a result. I just don't know where to begin.

I could loop through the worksheet and export JavaScript one liner codes into a text document, but I don't know how to write how to wait the browser to load and then capture the result. Even if the result is logged in a csv or text file, I could do something with it.

My data is similar to:

| Last Name | First Name | DOB | SSN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | John | 1/1/1970 | 111-11-1111 |
| Smith | Johnathan | 2/2/1990 | 222-22-2222 |

Code to Export to JS I have so far:

```
Public Function GenerateJavascript()

    Dim ws      As Worksheet
    Dim lRow    As Long
    Dim myStr   As String
    Dim myFile  As String

    Set ws = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\students.csv"
    Open myFile For Output As #1

    For i = 2 To lRow

        myStr = "document.getElementsByName(" & Chr(34) & "lnr_lastName" & Chr(34) & _
        ")(0).value = " & Chr(34) & ws.Cells(i, 5) & Chr(34)     

        Write #1, myStr

        myStr = "document.getElementsByName(" & Chr(34) & "lnr_firstName" & Chr(34) & _
        ")(0).value = " & Chr(34) & ws.Cells(i, 6) & Chr(34)

        Write #1, myStr

        myStr = "document.getElementsById(" & Chr(34) & "searchForm" & Chr(34) & _
        ").submit()"

        Write #1, myStr
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: If you can't use IE then you need to look at Selenium Basic: https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/

Comment: ...or if the database has an API you could maybe use that.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but if the root problem is that you need the data in the excel sheet to be queryable, maybe load the excel data into a DataTable, and then query that?